# Ordering while Rails has_many with typecast String to decimal

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many

I've `Size` model with `value` as a string. 
I would like to order `sizes` based on the `value` attribute by casting it to decimal.

`has_many :sizes, -> {order 'value ASC'}`, this is ordering based on alphabetical order.

I tried `has_many :sizes, -> {order 'value::integer ASC'}`, not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. We can `CAST` the field like below.

`has_many :sizes, -> { order 'CAST(value AS DECIMAL) ASC' }`.

Comment: It sounds like you are using the wrong column type, the cast works but I'd recommend you to consider using a DECIMAL column instead.

Comment: @arieljuod, I'm storing shoe sizes like 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5 like that, so using string field to store them.
I need to store 10 as 10, not 10.0.